# Laravel Missing required parameters for [Route: farmacia-detail] [URI: farmacia/{slug}]

Tags: php, laravel

recibo este error al intentar llamar a una ruta

```
    <a href="{{ route('farmacia-detail', $medicamento->slug) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Detalle</a>
cuando el llamado a ella en:
    @foreach ($medicamentos as $medicamento)
        <div class="col-sm">
          <div class="card text-center" style="width: 18rem; margin-top: 70px">
            <img style="height: 100px; width: 100px; backgroup-color: #EFEFEF; margin: 20px;" class="card-img-top
            rounded-circle mx-auto d-block"src="images/{{$medicamento->avatar}}" alt="">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{$medicamento->medicamento}}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">{{$medicamento->descripcion}}</p>
              <p class="card-text">{{$medicamento->laboraorio}}</p>
              <h3><span class="label label-success">${{$medicamento->precio,2}}</span></h3>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i>Add to Cart</a>
              <a href="{{ route('farmacia-detail', $medicamento->slug) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Detalle</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

Cuando llamo a farmacia-detail

mis rutas son:

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('usuario','UsuarioController');
Route::resource('medicamentos','MedicamentosController');
Route::resource('farmacia','FarmaciaController');
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('farmacia/{slug}',[
  'as' => 'farmacia-detail',
  'uses' => 'FarmaciaController@show'
]);
// carrito
Route::get('cart/show',[
  'as'=> 'cart-show',
  'uses' => 'CartController@show'
]);

Route::get('cart/add/{farmacia}',[
  'as'=> 'cart-add',
  'uses' => 'CartController@add'
]);
```

el controlador

```
  public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $medicamentos=Medicamento::medicamento($request->get('medicamento'))->orderBy('medicamento','DESC')->paginate();
        return view('medicamentos.index',compact('medicamentos'));
    }
  public function show($slug)
    {
        $medicamento=Medicamento::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        dd($medicamento);
    }
```

Comment: puede que tengas otra ruta similar, o algo asi. Puede existir confucion con alguna

Answer (score 0):

Con la información que muestras pueden ser varias las causas del error:

1. Conflicto con la ruta generada por el *resourceful route*.

   Las posibles soluciones en este caso son:

   a. Definir la ruta `farmacia-detail` antes de `Route::resource('farmacia',...);` en el archivo de rutas.

   b. Excluir la ruta `'show'` del resource:

   `Route::resource('farmacia',...)->except(['show']);`
2. Es posible que haya algún conflicto con las rutas almacenadas en el caché, o que no aparezca ahí simplemente, para esto hay que limpiar el caché de rutas y verificar con detalle el listado de rutas de artisan, incluso en casos más extremos, puede haber algún caché adicional ligado a PHP o al servidor.
3. Que no tome el valor correctamente el helper route (aunque esto depende de la versión de Laravel que utilices). La solución sería pasar el parámetro como un array en vez de un solo valor: `route('farmacia-detail', [$medicamento->slug]);`

Comment: gracias los probare a ver si se puede solucionar